# cakephp 2.6 current location in model layer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am in the model layer and want to make a switch() for the different prefixes like `admin` or `api`.

How can I get the request params I have in the Controller layer `$this->request->params` in the Model layer?

Comment: In short: You shouldn't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router::getParams()
```

This should do the job but, as AD7six said, don't do it